# Performance test vs Load test vs stress test

Tags: performance-testing, load-testing, stress-testing

I am testing web application which has been built by REST api. I want to simulate my application performance test, load test and stress test. Now I would like to know what is the difference among Performance test, Load test, stress test.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- [Performance Testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_performance_testing) - is a testing technique, it is not something you can apply to your web application directly. Performance testing is a sub-type of Non Functional testing and Load Testing and Stress Testing in their turns are lesser subsets of the Performance Testing.
- [Load Testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_performance_testing#Load_testing) - when you basically test how does your application act under **anticipated** load, i.e. you expect 500 concurrent users the process of asseessment your application under that load would be the Load Testing
- [Stress Testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_performance_testing#Stress_testing) - revealing the application boundaries and breaking points, finding bottlenecks, etc. It allows to have the following questions answered:

  - what is the maximum capacity of the system
  - how many users it may handle providing reasonable response time
  - what is the component which breaks first
  - does the system recover when the load gets back to normal

See [Why ‘Normal’ Load Testing Isn’t Enough](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/why-%E2%80%98normal%E2%80%99-load-testing-isn%E2%80%99t-enough) for more detailed explanation.